# How can I pre-select an option in a select menu based on a value stored in the database?

Tags: php

I have a number of dropdown lists, which update a database, however once updated the first object on the list is displayed, rather than the actual object selected.  What is the best way to fix this?

Code sample:
HTML code sample

```
<select name="sleeps">
       <option value="0">Sleeps</option>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

This is generated using:

```
 <?php 
                                for ($x = 1; $x <=10; $x++) {
                                    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
                                }
?>
```

**Desired result**

```
 <select name="sleeps">
       <option value="0">Sleeps</option>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4' selected>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *"once updated"* - can you walk us through a use case or something? The script i see 1. page loads, displaying the fetched select 2. user acts on the select box 3. **maybe** user presses save\apply 4. **is this what you mean by 'once updated'** the page reloads after user applies changes, but their selection isn't default.

Comment: `if x equals 4, do your thing`

Comment: Walk through:  User selects value from dropdown, selected value is submitted and inserted to a database.  Value selected in database is set to first value, which in this case would be '0'.  If submitted with no value selected, then '0' is inserted in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out :)

Note - $echo and $title are there to allow changes in order to allow flexibility.

```
function select_dropdown($sql, $echo, $title) {
include 'connect.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$select = $conn->prepare($sql);
$select->bind_param('s', $id);
$select->execute();
$select->store_result();
if ($select->num_rows > 0) {
    $meta = $select->result_metadata();
echo "<select name='$title'>
                        <option value='0'>$title</option>\n";
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($select, 'bind_result'), $params);
    while ($select->fetch()) {
                 for ($x = 1; $x <=10; $x++) {
             if ($row[$echo] == $x) {
                 echo "<option value='$row[$echo]' selected>$row[$echo]</option>";
             } else {
             echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
             }
                            }

    }
    $select->close();
    echo "</select>";
}

}
```

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to name a variable after a language construct (`$echo`), and it would make more sense to only print the `<option>` once. At first glance, it looks like you're printing something completely different, even though `$row[$echo]` and `$x` actually contain the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for ($x = 1; $x <=10; $x++) {
            $sel = ($x == $the_value) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='$x'$sel>$x</option>";
        }
```

For the record, mixing your PHP and HTML like this is very messy and not easily maintained.

Edit: Since you're likely new to PHP, I should mention this is called the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which is just a shorthand way of writing an if statement.